# Calculating Conditional Probability in a small cipher problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a small part of data that is n bit long (0 or 1). Probability that a bit is 0 equals p.
I also have a key that is used to cipher this data that is 1 bit long. The key will be 0 or 1 for the whole data (equal probability).
A XOR operation between the key and the data takes place, and we take the encrypted data.

If the encrypted data contains k zeros (and n-k ones), calculate the probability that the key used is 0.

I am trying to solve this. My thinking until now is that we have 2 events:

**Event(A).** Original data had k zeros

I can calculate through the binomial distribution.

$P(A) = {{n}\choose{k}}(p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $

**Event(B).** Encrypted data has k zeros
Since a XOR operator is applied if the key was 0, we will have k bits that are zero, if the key bit was 1 we will have n-k bits that are zero. So $P(B) = \frac{P(A)}{2}$

And then i am searching for the conditional probability 
$(P(key=0|P(B))$

Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $K$ be the event that the key is $1$. We seek for $P(K'|B)$, where $B$ conforms to your definition, i.e. encrypted data has $k$ zeros. Via Bayes rule, we could write:
$$P(K'|B)=\frac{P(B|K')P(K')}{P(B)}$$
Here $P(K')=1/2$, and $P(B|K')=P(A)$ (for $A$, I'm using your def. again) because when the key is $0$, having $k$ zeros means having $k$ zeros from the beginning. We can write $P(B)$ via total probability theorem:
$$P(B)=P(B|K')P(K')+P(B|K)P(K)=\frac{P(B|K')+P(B|K)}{2}$$
Here, $P(B|K)=P(n-k \ \text{zeros in the original data})={n \choose n-k}p^{n-k}(1-p)^k$. Summing the two yields (noting that ${n \choose k}={n \choose n-k}$):
$$P(K'|B)=\frac{p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}{p^k(1-p)^{n-k}+p^{n-k}(1-p)^k}=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{n-2k}}$$

Comments on your solution and notation:

As you can see $P(B)\neq P(A)/2$, instead $P(B \cap K')=P(A)/2$, i.e. the numerator in Bayes formulation. Also, $P(key=0|P(B))$ doesn't have meaning, instead you need to write $P(key=0|B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much gunes! It now starts to make sense!